# GTM is not registering Click URL from Image,

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Iam stuck with the code. The javascript variable Retimgexp is returning as "", Not sure why. It only returns "undefined" when I click on the body of the page.

Basically what I am trying to achieve is when user clicks on image i wanted to grab the href of the parent "a" element and push it ultimately to the GA TAG using variables, so i have made modifications to the code.

can you please have a look.

Custom javascript File name:- **Find closest**

```
    function() {    
      return function(target, selector) {
           while (!target.matches(selector) && !target.matches('body')) {
              target = target.parentElement;
            }
            return target.matches(selector) ? target : undefined;
          }    
    }
```

Custom javascript File name:- **Retimgexp**

```
   function() {   
          var el = {{Find closest}}({{Click Element}}, 'a[href^="http"]');
          return typeof el !== 'undefined' ? el.id : undefined;
           }
```

Basically this is the HTML code

```
<div class="card__media-overlapping__media">
    <a href="https://capgemini.aws.hmn.md/experts/it-strategy-and-transformation/yvette-zzauer/">
        <img src="https://eu-west-1.tchyn.io/capgemini-dev/uploads/2017/07/yvette_zzauer.jpg?resize=324,197" alt="Yvette Zzauer">
                </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its Working now

I was referencing the ID which was wrong should have referenced "href". Its working now.

```
function() {   
          var el = {{Find closest}}({{Click Element}}, 'a[href^="http"]');
          return typeof el !== 'undefined' ? el.href : undefined;
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

Oki one of the simplest way could be a one liner, then you can check for the fallback condition etc

```
{{Click Element}}.parentNode.getAttribute("href");
```